# How to Implement PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, algorithm, encryption

I am using PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to encrypt/decrypt a string in java.

```
 public static String encrypt(String originalPassword) throws Exception {
    String methodName = "encrypt -->";
    _logger.debug(methodName + Constants.CALLED);
    String encryptedString = null;
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
        encryptedString = base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(originalPassword.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        _logger.debug(methodName + "encrypted string " + encryptedString);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.error(methodName + "Encryption failed due to: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("Failed to Encrypt String");
    }
    _logger.debug(methodName + Constants.END);
    return encryptedString;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedPassword) throws Exception {
        String methodName = "decrypt -->";
        _logger.debug(methodName + Constants.CALLED);
        String decryptedString = null;
        try {
            _logger.debug(methodName + " string to decrypt " + encryptedPassword);
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
            decryptedString = new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(base64Decode(encryptedPassword)), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _logger.error(methodName + "Decryption failed due to: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("Failed to Decrypt String");
        }
        _logger.debug(methodName + Constants.END);
        return decryptedString;
    }
```

I have already define my own salt for this algorithm. But I want to encrypt few strings from JavaScript.

Can we implement same algorithm (PBEWithMD5AndDES) in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CryptoJS for this
Here is the URL
https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS

Comment: Many Thanks Mantu. Is it not possible to achieve encryption with PBEWithMD5AndDES in JS?

Comment: Here is the url of working fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/artjomb/Lpbo7yrb/

Comment: I really appreciate your reply but I want to know that, Can we do same thing with PBEWithMD5AndDES? If not then I will add CryptoJS code in front end and I also change my Java code accordingly.

Comment: You can invoke Java API using JS using REST call.

Comment: Next time, just flag the question as a duplicate instead of replicating content.